# evil quit-window and evil-record-macro integration

Tags: key-bindings, evil, functions

I am trying to replicate emacs standard behavior when it comes to 'q', i.e. when in a buffer where insert mode does not make sense 'q' closes it. So I defined the following function

```
(defun evil-new-record-macro ()
  (interactive)
    (cond
     (buffer-read-only (quit-window))
     (t (evil-record-macro ?0))
     ))
```

But `(evil-record-macro ?0)` is a bad idea since it assumes a '0' as an argument and I don't know how to use without a pre-specified register.

The question is the following:

Whats a more correct/better way to approach the letter 'q' behavior, macros when it makes sense and quit when it does not.

BONUS: How I can fix the function so it does not need a register to be pre specified.

assume that I am always in normal state and switching to emacs or motion is not an option. I also use general.el to bind keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call an interactive command, use `call-interactively`.  I've taken the liberty to simplify your code a bit:

```
(defun my-evil-record-macro ()
  (interactive)
  (if buffer-read-only
      (quit-window)
    (call-interactively 'evil-record-macro)))

(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "q") 'my-evil-record-macro))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I am still testing it to be sure it does exactly what I want context wise, It seems it is the case.